# Syntax highlighting WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

I'm trying to make a simple wp7 app but I need to highlight certain parts of a string.  such as `hello` in purple and `how are you?` in yellow how am i able todo this in C#?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way is to use a RichTextBox so you can 'style' the text with paragraphs and runs.
More info [here...](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee681613%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)